# How do I turn on my bluetooth for my msi-1754 laptop?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

The <kbd>fn</kbd> key doesn't work, and the <kbd>s</kbd> bar doesn't show bluetooth. I looked in the devices, and there isn't anything for Bluetooth. But supposedly there is supposed to be Bluetooth.

Comment: Sometimes laptop cases have the bluetooth led window, but no bluetooth is installed.  Do you see any evidence of bluetooth when you type   lsusb  ?

Comment: Where am I supposed to type that in at?

Comment: Start a terminal (either ctrl-alt-t  or from the dash (search for term). and then type in the command.